# Google Sheets lookup 2 columns and sum values of 3rd column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to summarize some data.  Each row has a Person's Name, Date, and Distance data.  For any date, a Person might have multiple rows, which I'm trying to combine by summing the distance of all activiites on that date.

Data looks like this:

| Name | Date | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | 12/25/2022 | 50 |
| Person1 | 12/26/2022 | 25 |
| Person1 | 12/26/2022 | 10 |
| Person2 | 12/25/2022 | 5 |
| Person2 | 12/26/2022 | 10 |
| Person2 | 12/27/2022 | 30 |

Summary table add up the total distances for each day:

| Name | 12/25/2022 | 12/26/2022 | 12/27/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | 50 | 35 | 0 |
| Person2 | 5 | 10 | 30 |

I can't figure out how to build an array for Person/Date to sum for just that date.

Here's an example sheet where I've tried various vlookup, sumif and other methods but need can't isolate the name-date combo.

Here's an example sheet.  Thanks!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQUlYD0gvLRm3n2JbEOxCw0JW7rDmKlvFsoyctjyans/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this QUERY:

```
=query(B:D,"Select B,SUM(D) where B is not null group by B pivot C",1)
```

[image]

Comment: for OP, if you want to display 0 instead of blank cells, use: `=ArrayFormula(lambda(table,if(table="",0,table))(query(B:D,"Select B,SUM(D) where B is not null group by B pivot C",1)))`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly and appreciate you putting them in my sheet.